# Primefaces RowToggle - How to differentiate between Row Expansion and Row Collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using Prmefaces 3.5. I use the RowToggler in a datatable. Whenever the RowToggle button is clicked, I use to do some database access operations and display a grid with the the accessed data.

Whenever the toggle button is clicked the below listener is called, in which the operations are done

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{controller.onRowToggle}"
```

But the problem lies in calling this method. Not only when the row is expanded, this method is called, but also when the row is collapsed. The database operations doesn't need to be done while the row is collapsed, and so this is turning out to be an expensive operation.

Please suggest how to know if the row is expanded or collapsed, so I could do the operations conditionally?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `ToggleEvent#getVisibility()` metod in your listener? Here's example:

```
public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
    if (event.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make the RT *only* if the row is being expanded, this will work:

```
<p:ajax
    event="rowToggle"                                            
    onstart="return cfg.ext.params[0].name.indexOf('_rowExpansion') != -1"
    listener="#{fooViewModel.onRowToggle}"
/>
```

Comment: This works like  a charm! The content of my selectOneMenu inside the rowExpansion has been reset and this was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: brilliant solution.
client sided

Comment: I realize the last comment was 10 months ago, but if you return false from any onstart, the ajax call will not occur

Comment: Does anybody know where I can find documentatino about other arguments that can be passed to onstart/oncomplete callbacks? I know you can pass `this` and, thanks to this answer, `cfg`. I there a place I can find other arguments that are available? I know you can pass `this` and `event` to an onclick handler as well.